# Getting Chrome extension error: Cannot find context with specified id and Inspector protocol error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, runtime-error, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create a basic extension using **chrome's dev-tools API**. I have created a panel in the developer-tools window and rendered the UI using pure HTML and ES6. But when I have created the same UI page in React(using create-react-app build) chrome dev tool is not rendering the UI and given following errors.

```
Cannot find context with specified id _evaluateGlobal @ shell.js:5111

Extension server error: Inspector protocol error: 
       Cannot find context with specified id makeStatus @ shell.js:7823
```

I have tried again by removing all other meta tags & service worker configs from the HTML, still, I am getting the same issue (I am able to render this react page properly in the browser window).

> **EDIT**: I am able to render a basic react page in chrome devtool panel using ReactJS in pure JavaScript way (not JSX, thanks to
>   Babel-REPL ). Only the issue is coming when using the **create-react-app** build.

Please see the code below,

**extension.js**

```js
    // Create a tab in the devtools area
    chrome.devtools.panels.create("Tool heading", "toast.png", "panel.html", function (panel) { 
        console.log(panel);
    });
```

**Panel.html(a basic material-UI react application with using create-react-app)**

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="./build/static/css/main.4742e13d.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./build/static/js/1.4698090b.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="./build/static/js/main.804b2e98.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Full error log:**

```
shell.js:3123 [Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use window.customElements.define instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more details.
UI.registerCustomElement @ shell.js:3123
shell.js:3081 [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960 for more details.
UI.createShadowRootWithCoreStyles @ shell.js:3081
shell.js:7924 Main._createAppUI: 24.008056640625ms
shell.js:7924 Main._showAppUI: 72.796875ms
shell.js:7924 Main._initializeTarget: 9.6240234375ms
shell.js:7924 Main._lateInitialization: 18.457275390625ms
devtools.js:4 Object
shell.js:5111 Cannot find context with specified id
_evaluateGlobal @ shell.js:5111
shell.js:7823 Extension server error: Inspector protocol error: Cannot find context with specified id
makeStatus @ shell.js:7823
```

Please share your thoughts, comments, and links.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: running in to the same error not sure what it means, did you figure it out/

Comment: @user299709 - No I did not. Instead, I have used normal script tag, I was running out of time.